# Fetching the response headers using Angular2

Tags: angular

I am not able to fetch the response headers coming from the http request using Angular2. I am getting response as '**null**'.

```
getTokenSession(username) {
    let url = this.urlLogin+'/login?username='+username;
       return this.http.post(url).map (
       result => {
           let data = result.json();
           let sessionID = result.headers.get('sessionid');               
           console.log(sessionID);
           return data;
       }
    )
  }
```

But i am able to see all the headers in the browser console.

[image]

Comment: do a quick test maybe? What do u get if u `console.log(result.headers.getAll()`?

Comment: is result a returned promise?

Comment: @chybie, i am getting error in JSON for getAll() method

Comment: `x.headers.getAll('sessionid')`?

Comment: i tried `x.headers.get('content-type')`, and it's working fine. Sorry x is your `result`.

Comment: @Chybie, that also i am getting 'null'. I think it is may be cross domain issue(CORS)?

Comment: Probably not. If you are getting `CORS` issue, you don't even get to read `result.json()`. I am assuming your `data` variable has value right?

Comment: @Chybie, yes, in that i am getting the 'auth-token' but the 'sessionid' is coming from response headers. i am not able fetch the 'sessionid'